# Performans & Diagnostics - Not Applicable Tools in VS2013 Ultimate

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, profiling, performance-testing

I use Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate on Windows 8.1 Pro and want to analyze performance metrics of my web project with profiler. But many tools in Performances & Diagnostic Tools section are disabled. I want use Memory Usage & CPU Usagem but the are listed as "**Not applicable tools**"

How can i use this tools??

Thanks for your help..

[image]

Comment: If no luck in getting answered here, try to post your question on Microsoft's VS Test Tools forum https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home?forum=vstest

Answer (score 11):

The "Available tools" are based on the project type. ASP.NET projects can only use the Performance Wizard tool. There is no way to make the other tools work for unsupported project types.